# OpenCV and Unsharp Masking Like Adobe Photoshop

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, reverse-engineering, photoshop

I am trying to implement unsharp masking like it's done in Adobe Photoshop. I gathered a lot of information on the interent but I'm not sure if I'm missing something. Here's the code:

```
void unsharpMask( cv::Mat* img, double amount, double radius, double threshold ) {

// create blurred img
cv::Mat img32F, imgBlur32F, imgHighContrast32F, imgDiff32F, unsharpMas32F, colDelta32F, compRes, compRes32F, prod;
double r = 1.5;
img->convertTo( img32F, CV_32F );
cv::GaussianBlur( img32F, imgBlur32F, cv::Size(0,0), radius );
cv::subtract( img32F, imgBlur32F, unsharpMas32F );
// increase contrast( original, amount percent ) 
imgHighContrast32F = img32F * amount / 100.0f;
cv::subtract( imgHighContrast32F, img32F, imgDiff32F );
unsharpMas32F /= 255.0f;
cv::multiply( unsharpMas32F, imgDiff32F, colDelta32F );
cv::compare( cv::abs( colDelta32F ), threshold, compRes, cv::CMP_GT );
compRes.convertTo( compRes32F, CV_32F );

cv::multiply( compRes32F, colDelta32F, prod );
cv::add( img32F, prod, img32F );

img32F.convertTo( *img, CV_8U );
}
```

At the moment I am testing with a grayscale image. If i try the exact same parameters in Photoshop I get much better result. My own code leads to noisy images. What am I doing wrong.

The 2nd question is, how i can apply unsharp masking on RGB images? Do I have to unsharp mask each of the 3 channels or would it be better in another color space? How are these things done in Photoshop?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

I'm trying to replicate Photoshop's Unsharp Mask as well.
Let's ignore the Threshold for a second.

I will show you how to replicate Photoshop's Unsharp Mask using its Gaussian Blur.

Assuming O is the original image layer.

Create a new layer GB which is a Gaussian Blur applied on O.
Create a new layer which is O - GB (Using Apply Image).
Create a new layer by inverting GB - invGB.
Create a new layer which is O + invGB using Image Apply.
Create a new layer which is inversion of the previous layer, namely inv(O + invGB).
Create a new layer which is O + (O - GB) - inv(O + invGB).

When you do that in Photoshop you'll get a perfect reproduction of the Unsharp Mask.

If you do the math recalling that inv(L) = 1 - L you will get that the Unsharp Mask is
USM(O) = 3O - 2B.

Yet when I do that directly in MATLAB I don't get Photoshop's results.

Hopefully someone will know the exact math.

### Update

OK,
I figured it out.
In Photoshop USM(O) = O + (2 * (Amount / 100) * (O - GB))
Where GB is a Gaussian Blurred version of O.

Yet, in order to replicate Photoshop's results you must do the steps above and clip the result of each step into [0, 1] as done in Photoshop.

Comment: How did you found magical "2 * " multiplier in this formula? I've seen the same math in pixastic and other sources, but without 2x multiply (though they did not pretended to be equal to photoshop)

Comment: By understanding what Photoshop does.

Comment: Could you take a look at this demo http://nodeca.github.io/pica/demo/ ? I've implemented your formula. It's applied to brightness (0.299*R + 0.587*G + 0.114*B). Then found brightness diffecence is used to scale RBG channels. Is it ok, that big "unsharp amount" cause color drift?

Comment: @Vitaly, I'm not sure I got you. Anyhow, Photoshop applies it to all RGB Channels. If you want only the luminosity, you need to do it by conversion.

Comment: @Drazik, devil is in details. Generic formula is clear, but it's not clear if transforms applied on each channel independently or via something like "luminosity" (via grayscale, hsl or LAB space). I could not get exact answer anywhere. But a lot of mentions, that independent RGB transforms are not perfect due color drift. I suspect, that photoshop does not use direct independent channels transforms.

Comment: @Vitaly, As I said, by default it works on all channels independently. If you want to apply it only on the luminosity you either do it using blending mode or go to the LAB, chose the L channel, apply and transform back. Again, it operates on all channels of the input image.

Comment: @Vitaly, I think the 2x multiplier is incorrect and results from ignoring clamping in this formula:

USM(o) = o + Amount / 100 * [(o - GB) - (1 - (o + (1 - GB)))]

See my extended reply.

Answer (score 1):

## According to docs:

> C++: void GaussianBlur(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, Size ksize,
>   double sigmaX, double sigmaY=0, int borderType=BORDER_DEFAULT )

4th parameter is not "radius" it is "sigma" - gaussian kernel standard deviation. Radius is rather "ksize". Anyway Photoshop is not open source, hence we can not be sure they use the same way as OpenCV to calculate radius from sigma.

## Channels

Yes you should apply sharp to any or to all channels, it depends on your purpose. Sure you can use any space: if you want sharp only brightness-component and don't want to increase color noise you can covert it to HSL or Lab-space and sharp L-channel only (Photoshop has all this options too).

Comment: I think you meant to say convert to HSV, not HSL (if you want to sharpen brightness only).  V is brightness.  L is lightness.  Sharpening V avoids color shift.

Answer (score 0):

In response to @Royi, the 2x multiplier results from assuming no clamping in this formula:

```
USM(Original) = Original + Amount / 100 * ((Original - GB) - (1 - (Original + (1 - GB))))
```

Ignoring clamping this incorrectly reduces to:

```
USM(Original) = Original + 2 * Amount / 100 * (Original - GB)
```

However, as you also point out, `(Original - GB)` and `(Original + inv(GB))` are clamped to [0, 1]:

```
USM(Original) = Original + Amount / 100 *
   (Max(0, Min(1, Original - GB)) - (1 - (Max(0, Min(1, Original + (1 - GB))))))
```

This correctly reduces to:

```
USM(Original) = Original + Amount / 100 * (Original - GB)
```

Here is an example illustrating why:

https://legacy.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?p=133597#p133597

Answer (score -2):

Here's the code what I have done.
I am using this code to implement Unsharp Mask and it is working well for me.
Hope it is useful for you.

```
void USM(cv::Mat &O, int d, int amp, int threshold)
{
    cv::Mat GB;
    cv::Mat O_GB;
    cv::subtract(O, GB, O_GB);

    cv::Mat invGB = cv::Scalar(255) - GB;

    cv::add(O, invGB, invGB);

    invGB = cv::Scalar(255) - invGB;

    for (int i = 0; i < O.rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < O.cols; j++)
        {
            unsigned char o_rgb = O.at<unsigned char>(i, j);
            unsigned char d_rgb = O_GB.at<unsigned char>(i, j);
            unsigned char inv_rgb = invGB.at<unsigned char>(i, j);

            int newVal = o_rgb;
            if (d_rgb >= threshold)
            {
                newVal = o_rgb + (d_rgb - inv_rgb) * amp;
                if (newVal < 0)      newVal = 0;
                if (newVal > 255)    newVal = 255;
            }

            O.at<unsigned char>(i, j) = unsigned char(newVal);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This implementation simply doesn't work.