# How to implement unsharp masking on an image in C++ without using prepared OpenCv functions?

Tags: c++, image-processing

how to apply the Unsharp Masking method to enhance the edges of image?

Comment: This is far to broad a question and well beyond scope for this forum.

Comment: You can apply the algorithm by accessing the individual pixels in your image, using the `at` method in `cv::Mat`.

Comment: yes I can reach the pixels of the image by using cv::Mat but the point is in my homework , I'm not allowed to use the functions like that:GaussianBlur( src, dst, Size( i, i ), 0, 0 ); @unxnut

Comment: I think this [link](http://lodev.org/cgtutor/filtering.html) will help you. You will need a filter (express in a matrix like structure)... and go through the image  applying this structure. In the link you can find some examples of the structure and what it does (different filters).

Comment: You could use ImageMagick's Magick++ api to access its functions to do your filtering

Comment: I assumed that you know the unsharp masking algorithm and just want to implement it without using the OpenCV functions.  Once you access the pixels, you can convolve over them in a nested loop using the kernel for unsharp masking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [link](http://lodev.org/cgtutor/filtering.html) can really helps you.

How does it work? Using a matrix as filter parameter (kernel), you go through each pixel of the image, where the new pixel will be the matrix applied to that position.

```
[0   0.2   0]
[0.2 0.2 0.2]
[0   0.2   0]
```

For example, you can use the matrix above and apply for every pixel in the image. The above matrix will take the average of the current pixel and its neighbors.

By unsharp masking, I think you are talking about [blur.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938162/how-does-an-unsharp-mask-work?rq=1) The before mentioned matrix will blur the image. You can check the link for example of more filters and the result.

If in your homework you are allowed to use other functions from OpenCV, you can use [`filter2D` to apply a kernel](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/filter_2d/filter_2d.html). If not, you can go through pixel by pixel using the method `at` from the `mat`... reading the pixel from the original mat, writing the result in a different one.

This [website](http://setosa.io/ev/image-kernels/) explain in details how a kernel works. In addition, they have a live implementation where you can try some different matrices.